# Copy content from a div + styles to a new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to copy the content from a div, create new window and put the content inside.

The code is working, but is not getting the styles. How can I copy all the styles references from source page?

Ps.: I'm using bootstrap + react

```
function PrintElem() {

    var nWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
    let content = document.getElementById('printablediv').innerHTML;
    content.print();
    nWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title>');
    nWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    nWindow.document.write(content);
    nWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    nWindow.document.close();
    nWindow.focus();

    nWindow.print();
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Why would you need to do that?

Comment: I want to put the content in a new window and print.

Comment: Why do you need a new window? Why not just use the same one?

Comment: Hint: It's fairly easy to hide everything _except_ the element you want to print with media queries in your CSS.

Comment: how? can you give an example?

Comment: `div {display: none;} .print-element {display: block;}` [Targeting media types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#targeting_media_types)

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered how: You need to copy the header properties. It's where the css references stay.

```
export const PrintElement = (item) => {

    var nWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
    let element = document.getElementById(item);
    let header = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
    nWindow.document.write('<html>');
    nWindow.document.write('<header>');
    for (let headItem of header) {
        nWindow.document.write(headItem.outerHTML);
    }
    nWindow.document.write('</header>');
    nWindow.document.write('<body >');
    nWindow.document.write(element.outerHTML);
    nWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    nWindow.document.close();
    nWindow.focus();

    nWindow.print();
}
```